# how to resolve the jenkins problem to create the maven job

Tags: jenkins

Started by user devopsadmin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/indigo-ms
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified

> /bin/git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/indigo-ms/.git # timeout=10
> Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> /bin/git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/RKnagre/indigo.git # timeout=10
> Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/RKnagre/indigo.git
> /bin/git --version # timeout=10
> git --version # 'git version 2.39.2'
> /bin/git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/RKnagre/indigo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
> /bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/dev^{commit} # timeout=10
> Checking out Revision a568ee82a5685f1c3b89b0376e1298902655bb03 (refs/remotes/origin/dev)
> /bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> /bin/git checkout -f a568ee82a5685f1c3b89b0376e1298902655bb03 # timeout=10
> Commit message: "codepush"
> /bin/git rev-list --no-walk a568ee82a5685f1c3b89b0376e1298902655bb03 # timeout=10
> ERROR: Maven Home /opt/apache-maven-3.8.7 doesnt exist
> Finished: FAILURE

how to create maven job in jenkins and get the github code in that job?

Comment: What is the maven command being run?

Comment: is it a git problem? According to the error it seems that maven 3.8.7 can not be found: ERROR: Maven Home /opt/apache-maven-3.8.7 doesnt exist""